# jquery validate with html5 pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

How do i make jQuery validate/support an HTML 5 pattern? It would be great if it did without specifying the pattern on each field.

I know I could do this (below), but is there better way?

```
$("form").validate({
  rules: {
    "password": {
      pattern: /[A-Za-z0-9\w]{4,20}/,
    }
  }
});
```

See Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2ma8ec6j/

Comment: FYI you should be able to remove the `^` from that pattern (the regexes are always full `match()` style - see [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern)).

Comment: How can I add multiple pattern matching for OR condition

Comment: write a pattern that has or condition. I dont know how  but it should be standard regex

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Quote**:

> *"How do i make jQuery validate/support an HTML 5 pattern?"*

It already does.  See below

> *"It would be great if it did without specifying the pattern on each field."*

How will it know which pattern goes to which field if you don't specify this someplace?

---

> *"...is there better way?"*

You can declare *some* rules via inline HTML attributes.  However, you can declare *all* rules via the `rules` option within `.validate()` or the `.rules()` method.

I don't know if this is "better" as that is purely a matter of opinion, but as long as you include the [`additional-methods.js`](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/additional-methods.js) OR the [`pattern.js`](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/additional/pattern.js) file, the jQuery Validate plugin will pickup and use the HTML5 `pattern` attribute.

```
<input type="text" name="somename" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9\w]{4,20}" />
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/fLxgz9dn/**

See:  https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/785

Comment: Tried same as yours it didn't work for mine. let be debug a bit if not i will paste a fiddle

Comment: @aWebDeveloper, it works when you declare it within `.validate()` but not when you declare it inline?  Something else you haven't shown must be breaking it, so we need to wait for you to reproduce the issue within a jsFiddle.

Comment: i think i was missing additional methods